# .htaccess SSL problems main domain vs subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

Hi I can't seem to find the correct answer anywhere, maybe you guys can help out. I have the SSL certificate installed correctly on the main domainname of my site.

I'd need htaccess to :

1. Enforce https for the main domainname and strip out the www.
2. And then next, make sure there's no https: enforced for my subdomain - http://forums.example.com

I only find partial solutions to this problem and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://domainname\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: hi anubhava, thank you for looking into this! but this seems to create an endless loop. chrome doing nothing and safari after a few loops showing "localhost" in the address bar...

Comment: See modified rule. Make sure this is your first rule and you test in a new browser. If it still loops then open in Firebug and see what redirects you see in Net tab.

Comment: thanks anubhava. it's not going in an endless loop anymore. it enforces the SSL and strips out the www redirecting fine for the main domainname, but when going to http://forums.example.com it just makes it go to https://example.com

Comment: ok can you try updated code again after clearing browser cache.

Comment: this works perfect now. awesome. i'd buy you a beer.